# Building sub projects using NANT

Tags: c#, .net, nant

I'm trying to build a project(A) using NANT. The project(A) relies upon another project(B) which is also built with NANT. I want to be able to invoke the build of the dependent project(B) from within the build of project(A). I've tried including the build file of project B in the build file of project A. This creates an error because the two build files contain targets that share the same name.

Is there a way to alias the included build file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to do this using an include task but have found that the nant task is actually what I required.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this by creating a "parent" buildfile, that uses the "nant" action to call other buildfiles.

```
<target name="rebuild" depends="" >
    <nant target="${target::get-current-target()}">
        <buildfiles>
            <include name="projectB.build" />
            <include name="projectC.build" />
        </buildfiles>
    </nant>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have several of such targets in your 'master' file. I often use the following construction to share a set of build files between targets to make script maintenance easier.

```
<fileset id="buildfiles.all">
    <include name="projectB.build"/>
    <include name="projectB.build"/>
</fileset>

<target name="build">
    <nant target="${target::get-current-target()}">
        <buildfiles refid="buildfiles.all" />
    </nant>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <nant target="${target::get-current-target()}">
        <buildfiles refid="buildfiles.all" />
    </nant>
</target>

<target name="publish">
    <nant target="${target::get-current-target()}">
        <buildfiles refid="buildfiles.all" />
    </nant>
</target>
```